# JS Ajax Unspecified error on new XMLHttpRequest() on IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**I use ajax for call remote webpage,this works on ff,chrome and ie correctly,
 i test using develop site and it works correctly**

**also the header files on remote page allows the cross domain request,**

but when i add this code to live site it giving. this gives on ie other browsers are working fine

**SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error on xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();**

i also changed the headers to allow request from live site, but no luck can any one help me please

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XDomainRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XDomainRequest();
        xmlhttp.onload = function(){ //alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
        };
    }
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://oncorecables.com/stock/jumi/cross.php',true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

live site
http://mychatterbook.com/profiles/members/

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using IE8 in InPrivate mode?

There is a bug in IE8 which causes cross-domain HTTP requests using the XDomainRequests object to fail when the user is browsing in InPrivate Browsing mode (See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).

I myself have worked around this by using jQuery's `$.get()` method. If you're not using jQuery in your website, you might want to go through jQuery's source code to investigate how they've worked around this as they apparently have managed to do this.